# Postgres - Use table name (passed in parameter) in function body

Tags: postgresql, function

I am a newbie wrt functions and I am struggling with using the name of a table in the function body. I get an error "SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "tname" does not exist" when I call the function using

```
select "JsonToView"('data_import.import_360xero_report');
```

My code is below

```
create or replace
function data_import."JsonToView"(tname text) returns numeric
language plpgsql 
as $function$ 
begin 
    do 
    $$
declare
    l_keys text;

begin 
    
drop view if exists v_json_view cascade;

select
    string_agg(distinct format('import_data ->> %L as %I', jkey, jkey), ', ')
into
    l_keys
from
    import_360xero_report,
    json_object_keys(import_data) as t(jkey);

execute 'create view v_json_view as select ' || l_keys || ' from ' || tname;
end;

$$; 
return 0;
end $function$ ;
```

I have modified the code and the second create view query works with the table name but the first one does not.

Below if my modified code

```
create or replace
function data_import."JsonToView"(tname text) returns numeric
language plpgsql 
as $function$ 

declare
    l_keys text;

begin 
    
drop view if exists v_json_view cascade;

execute $a$select
    string_agg(distinct format('import_data ->> %L as %I', jkey, jkey), ', ')
into
    l_keys
from $a$ ||
    tname || $b$,
    json_object_keys(import_data) as t(jkey)$b$;

execute 'create view v_json_view as select ' || l_keys || ' from ' || tname;


return 0;
end $function$ ;
```

The error I am getting is

```
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO is not implemented
  Hint: You might want to use EXECUTE ... INTO or EXECUTE CREATE TABLE ... AS instead.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function "JsonToView"(text) line 10 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: Hard to believe. In which line is the error reported?

Comment: What is this `begin do` supposed to be doing? I would lose that and the inner nesting `$$` quotes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the error is on line 17. The exact error message is "SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "tname" does not exist
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 17 at EXECUTE..."

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am double checking but I think what you have suggested seems to be working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the superfluous nested `DO` statement.

The variable `tname` exists only in the scope of the function, not in the nested `DO` statement. `DO` is an SQL statement, not a PL/pgSQL statement, and there are no variables in SQL. Also, `DO` does not allow parameters.

Get rid of the `DO` and you will be fine.

Comment: This works great. I have modified the code. The second issue I am running into  (and let me know if I need to create a separate thread for it) is that the execute query with the first select statement now results in an error

Comment: I do not think that is the issue as I am not getting the cannot find column error, instead I am getting a 

`SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO is not implemented
  Hint: You might want to use EXECUTE ... INTO or EXECUTE CREATE TABLE ... AS instead.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function "JsonToView"(text) line 10 at EXECUTE`

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be `EXECUTE $$SELECT x INTO var FROM ...$$;`, but `EXECUTE $$SELECT x FROM ...$$ INTO var;`.